# Print Int and String

Tags: java

How can I make a method to print both integers and strings?
I tried

```
public static void print(String txt){
    System.out.println(txt);
}
```

This way I can only print Strings.

Sorry for my noobish question but I tried searching, but nothing (I'm propably using the wrong keywords)

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Do you know what method parameters are? This is a rhetorical question meant to make you search for `method parameters`.

Comment: Yes? Aren't they the stuff in the brackets after the method?

Comment: Right, the part next to the method name, ex `print`, is a list of parameters enclosed in parentheses. If you declare a parameter as type `String`, the method can only take `String` arguments.

Comment: Also, on top of everyone's answers, `println` itself is overloaded, so you can do `System.out.println(1)` and `System.out.println("1")`.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always say `System.out.println("Some string " + someNumber);`.  The compiler interprets "+" in that context to mean "Convert the non-String stuff to String and concatenate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to different signatures, you can also just use a generic parameter, such as an Object, and let Java do some [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for you:

```
class Untitled {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        U.log("test");
        U.log(45);
    }

    // U(tility)
    public static class U
    {
        public static void log( Object o )
        {
            System.out.println( o.toString() );            
        }
    }
}
```

I use one of those that takes an arbitrary number of parameters in every Java based project I work on.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Yes, what it allows you to do is not write the same method `N` times, where `N` is the number of different objects you want to print out. Say you add a `Person`. If you implement `toString()`, you can use my method with no modifications. If you use your paradigm, you have to make another method that takes a Person. Leveraging polymorphism is a good thing. **EDIT:** I was asked what benefit this had over the proposed structure.

Comment: (right, and I deleted my comment from earlier because it occurred to me right after I posted it)

Answer (score 3):

You can have different signatures with the same method name.

```
public static void print(String txt){
    System.out.println(txt);
}
public static void print(int txt){
    System.out.println(txt);
}
```

You can even "parse" or "clean" arguments to end using the same logic and reduce code.. something like this:

```
public static void print(String txt){
    System.out.println(txt);
}
public static void print(int number){
    print(Integer.toString(number));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overloading it.

```
public static void print (String txt) {
    System.out.println(txt);
}

public static void print (int txt) {
    System.out.println(txt);
}
```

*Or* converting all values to strings before passing it to the function using the Object [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method.

Comment: You mean overloading.

Comment: Yes, my bad guys, overloading (same method name, different signature).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to look into is called `method overloading`. Overloaded methods are those
which have same name but a different method signature. That will allow you to perform the same operation on different data.

For example, calculating the area of various 2D shapes. You can have one method as such:

```
public void area(int length,int breadth){ // for rectangle and squares
    //logic here
}
```

and another as such:

```
public void area(int radius){ // guess who ?
    //logic here
}
```

Now, based on your needs, call the appropriate method.

This is just supposed to be an addition to the answer that has already been posted by `porfiriopartida` .

Here is the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

---

Having said that, another option that you have is using `Object` class as the argument to the method. `Object` is the big daddy for all Java classes.
Tutorial: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectclass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object object. It is a generic class for all the java objects.

```
public static void print(Object txt){
    System.out.println(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Using generics
----------------
package simlpe;

public class simple
{                        
   public static < E > void print( E input)
   {

         System.out.println(input);
    }

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        // Creates a  Integer, Double and Character
        Integer A = 1;
        Double d = 1.1;
        Character ch = 'H';


        print( A ); // pass an Integer
        print( d ); // pass a Double 
        print( ch ); // pass a Character 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You don't get any benefit from using generics for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SamplePrint
{

  public static void main(String txt)
  {
    System.out.println(txt);
  }

  public static void main(int txt)
  {
    System.out.println(txt);
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    // This will automatically calls to print() which has string type arguments
    print("Hello Friend");

    // This will automatically calls to print() which has int type arguments
    print(100);
  }
}
```